# Admob Integrating - issue

Tags: android, integration, admob

I am integrating AdMob into my Android application.

My `main.xml`:

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               ads:adUnitId="XXX"
                               ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                               ads:adSize="BANNER" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

My `manifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
```

My class:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I'm using Android 2.1. When I run on the emulator, it shows me:

> You Must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

From the [AdMob Documentation](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html):

AdMob 4.3.1 requires you to add some additional configChanges to the AdActivity in your manifest.  The AdActivity entry should now look like this.

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

These new configChanges weren't introduced until Android 3.2, so you will need to get at least the Android 3.2 SDK, and set `target=android-13` in your project.properties to compile against the Android 3.2 SDK.

Don't worry, you can still run your app on 2.1 and above.  The AdMob SDK still supports every version since 1.5.  To allow your app to run on 2.1 and above, set the `android:minSdkVersion` of the [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) element to 7.

One last note: Since you are using the `ads:loadAdOnCreate` attribute in your xml, you don't need to load the ad in code.

Comment: i've updated but its shows me the same problem... can anybody send me an apps with admob integrated on my email? xhevadabduli@hotmail.com pls help

Comment: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize')

Comment: Did you set your target to android-13?  Is the Android library that you're using Android 3.2?

Comment: Ok @Eric i set to androi-13 but its dont show me any ads it is a problem have not ads for showing... thanks

Comment: Then it is probably an issue where it takes some time and requests for your app id to start serving ads.  Try adding `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"` to your AdView xml element, and see if test ads are returned.

Comment: i add but same issue nothing... what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any logcat output?